# How to handle dependencies which are fetched asynchronously in node?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a class that fetches a dependency asynchronously:

```
function MyClass() {
  this.dependency = fetchDepencyAsync();
}
```

I then have to do this in all its methods

```
MyClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {
    this.dependency.then(function(dependency) {
      // actual method code
    });
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: There's no magic bullet solution to this, you'll either have to do it the way you're doing it, or resolve the dependency up front before allowing the class to be interacted with. Both options result in somewhat odd ways of handling it.

Comment: I would prefer building a function that returns a promise that resolves with the ready to use instance of `MyClass`.